# How to fetch deeply nested data from the response body into state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, stateful

I've created a show page in react that is supposed to display the name of the selected student, the instrument(s) they play, and their assignments.

The database (simplified): user(student) data >many-to-many-relationship< instrument >many-to-many-relationship< assignment

While I can pull a single user(student) object into state and display that student's name, accessing the associated instrument(s) and assignment(s) has been stumping me.

Here's what the `body.user` looks like when I log it to the console:

```
{user: {…}}
  user:
    assignments: Array(1)
      0: {id: 6, name: "Concert Cb Scale", description: "Record this 
         scale to Ensemble at the start of the …nscribe the scale if 
         your instrument requires it!", created_at: "2018-11- 
         24T22:16:51.460Z", updated_at: "2018-11-24T22:16:51.460Z"}
      length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
  first_name: "June"
  id: 10
  instrument_sections: Array(1)
    0: {id: 7, instrument: "french horn", created_at: "2018-11- 
       24T22:16:51.356Z", updated_at: "2018-11-24T22:16:51.356Z"}
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
  last_name: "Cenadaigh"
```

I can't seem to get at `body.user.instrument_sections` (and thenceforth to `instrument:`).  I haven't attempted getting at `body.user.assignments` since it looks to me like I'll get the same errors.

The error in question is, from the console: "Error in fetch: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, instrument, created_at, updated_at}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `StudentShow`."  I understand that it's having an issue that I'm pointing at an object within the user object, but I don't understand how to go about the suggestions the error makes.  Furthermore, if I try to change `this.setState({ . . . instrumentSections: body.user.instrument_sections` to include `.instrument`, the console comes back with simply `undefined`.

My further attempts to get at `instrument` have come from:

1. Trying to figure out what should go between `body.user.instrument_sections` and `.instrument` (if anything).
2. How to `map` through `body.user` or the `student` state to get at the `instrument` and put it into state.  (Eventually, I'll have seed data that will have students with multiple instruments instead of just one, so I have that state held in an array.)

And finally, here's the code I currently have:

```
class StudentShow extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      student: {},
      instrumentSections: [],
      assignments: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    let studentId = this.props.params.id
    console.log(`${this.props.params.id}`)
    fetch(`/api/v1/users/${studentId}`)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response;
      } else {
        let errorMessage = `${response.status} 
        (${response.statusText})`;
        error = new Error(errorMessage);
        throw(error);
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      console.log(body);
      this.setState({ student: body.user, instrumentSections: 
        body.user.instrument_sections })
      console.log(this.state.student);
      console.log(this.state.instrumentSections);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(`Error in fetch: ${error.message}`));
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="text-center student-show">
        <h1>{this.state.student.first_name} 
          {this.state.student.last_name}</h1>
        <h2>Your section(s): </h2>
        <h4></h4>
        <h2>This week's assignment(s): </h2>
        <h4></h4>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to get access to `this.state.student. instrument_sections` where `instrument_sections` looks something like this:

`["french horn", "tuba", "trombone"]`

Is that correct?

Comment: That will become the goal once I can get instruments (like "french horn", "tuba", "trombone") into state, which is the current goal and I'm finding tricky since the instruments with which I want to build the array are deeply nested in the fetch body.  I'm about to try amirify's suggestion.  Fingers crossed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Me and the guy I worked with aren't sure if it's the most efficient method or if it's kosher with reactjs style, but at long last, the following javascript loop and accessories will work.  After `.then(response => response.json())`:

`.then(body => {
    const sections = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < body.user.instrument_sections.length; i++){        sections.push(body.user.instrument_sections[i].instrument);
    };`

And change the `setState` to this:

`this.setState({ student: body.user, instrumentSections: sections)}`

So what happens is js reaches into the body and through iteration grabs each relevant instrument, which goes into the `sections` array, and finally you set the state of `instrumentSections` equal to `sections`.

Comment: -1?  Uh oh.  Did I break etiquette?  Is there something particularly wrong with the solution even if it's functional?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your console`instrument_sections` is an array of objects so to get the first instrument for example you should get it like:
`body.user.instrument_sections[0].instrument`.
and instead of `instrumentSections: body.user.instrument_sections` try
`instrumentSections: body.user.instrument_sections.slice()` or
`instrumentSections: Array.from(body.user.instrument_sections)`
and let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, but it's still progress, thank goodness!


After brushing up on the functions you're suggesting, I totally see where you're going. (updating . . .)

Comment: `body.user.instrument_sections[0].instrument` works to get the first instrument, which is encouraging.  `instrumentSections: body.user.instrument_sections.slice()` and
`instrumentSections: Array.from(body.user.instrument_sections)` don't work (same error), but I bet they're close: both try putting each `instrument_sections` object into state whereas I need to look within each `instrument_sections` to the `instrument` key and extract its pair.  If I could somehow do something like `body.user.instrument_sections[all].instrument` I'd be in business.  Perhaps use some `forEach()` fx or the like?